# Calling a factory to return a type with Unity IoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a factory:

```
public class FooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    public IFoo CreateFoo(IBar bar)
    {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

My Unity container needds to get a resolve a `Foo`.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();
conatiner.RegisterType<IFooFactory,FooFactory>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IBar>())
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(????????);  //What should be here?
```

How do I tell Unity to call the method on the Factory in order to get an `IFoo`?

Comment: What's the point of having a FooFactory if you're not going to use it to generate new Foos?

Comment: @matt The factory is in a different assembly, in 'real life' it constructs a complicated `Foo` so that the container in the parent assembly is decoupled from the consumed assembly;  currently the parant assembly is having to build the full `Foo`, so is aware of all the intimate details on the internals of `Foo`.

Comment: This is why I don't like the use of `Foo` and `Bar` in example code ;) It's difficult to determine what your code is trying to do.  Assembly and linking issues aside, you have a class whose purpose is to generate instances of an `IFoo` - this is what you should use to get an `IFoo`.

Comment: @matt Actually, I agree with you w.r.t Foo & Bar.  I was trying to make it generalised.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to over-engineer this - You have a class (`FooFactory`) that:

- When given an `IBar` instance,
- Returns an `IFoo` instance

Use the factory to generate your `IFoo` instances:

```
public class Greeter
{
  private readonly IFooFactory _fooFactory;

  public Greeter(IFooFactory fooFactory)
  {
    _fooFactory = fooFactory;
  }

  public string SayHelloWithABar(IBar bar)
  {
    IFoo foo = _fooFactory.CreateFoo(bar);

    // do something with your 'foo' instance ...

    return "hello!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Aye, but I'd like Unity to call that method.  I can do it that way, it just felt more 'correct' to have Unity do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using an `InjectionFactory`. I do however recommend you switch to use the `IFooFactory` as a dependency in `Bar`. It makes the code easier to follow.

Better:

```
public class Bar
{
    private IFoo _foo;

    public Bar(IFooFactory fooFactory)
    {
        _foo = fooFactory.Create(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, what do you mean by "`IFooFactory` as a dependency in 'Bar'"?

Comment: constructor injection like in the example that I added.

Comment: In general you should prevent doing anything 'useful' in a constructor of a service (anything but storing incoming dependencies). The example seems weird, since factories are mainly meant to delay object graph construction, but in this case you don't delay construction, because you call the factory inside the constructor. In this case, why not inject `IFoo` directly into the constructor?